# Não criar tabela na API, usar a que tenho

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Fiz uma api em nodejs que o **models** é:

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const RESP_CC = sequelize.define('RESP_CC', {
    RCC_RESP: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(6),
      allowNull: false, //se aceita nulo
      autoIncrement: false
    },
    RCC_CCT: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(15),
      allowNull: false, //se aceita nulo
      autoIncrement: false
    },
    R_E_C_N_O_:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false, //se aceita nulo
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    D_E_L_E_T_: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(1),
      allowNull: false, //se aceita nulo
      autoIncrement: false
    }

  }, {});
  RESP_CC.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return RESP_CC;
};
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
class RESP_CC {

    async list(db) {

       return await db.RESP_CC.findAll({
        where: {
            RCC_CCT: '130103'
           }
       })

    }
}


export default new RESP_CC();
```

**ROUTER:**

```
module.exports = (routes, db) => {

    routes.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
        const user = await User.list(db);
        if (user) {
            res.status(200).send(user);
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({ message: 'No Data Found' });
        }
    });
};
```

E ela criou uma tabela, mas eu preciso usar a que ja existe no banco, há alguma forma de fazer sem precisar criar uma tabela no bd?

Comment: Oi Maria, por acaso você tem alguma chamada para um método sync? No meu exemplo eu uso assim: sequelize.sync()
Caso você esteja utilizando, basta apenas remover. O método sync, faz com que a criação de tabelas seja realizada automaticamente.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html

Comment: eu nao quero que crie uma tabela, eu quero apenas fazer uma consulta na tabela que ja existe no meu banco

Comment: Como o guilherme falou, você deve ter em algum lugar da sua aplicação o trecho de código similar a isso `sequelize.sync()`,  basta você remove lo que ele não irá criar a tabela e apenas mapear a que já existe.

Comment: @JustCase atualizei a pergunta. sequelize.sync() nao tem, mas tem sequelize.define

Comment: @GuilhermeNass  entao no lugar no sync() eu deixo o que? é no meu arquivo www
db.sequelize.sync()
    .then(() => {
        server.listen(port);
        server.on('error', onError);
        server.on('listening', onListening);
    });

Comment: @Maria imagino que esse server.listen() sirva para subir a aplicação.

Você pode remover o codigo do sequelize.sync() e iniciar a aplicação dessa forma:

         app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function(){
      console.log('server is up')
         })  

A variável app pode ser definida assim se você estiver usando Express:
var app = express()

Comment: @GuilhermeNass eu faço isso pra conectar no bd tbm, mas antes de vc responder eu fiz a seguinte alteração: `db.sequelize.transaction() 
    .then(() => { 
        server.listen(port); 
        server.on('error', onError); 
        server.on('listening', onListening);
})` e funcionou, nao ta mais criando tabela. Assim também está correto?

Comment: @Maria Nunca utilizei o transaction, mas pelo que vi na documentação parece atender sim.

"O objeto de transação é usado para identificar uma transação em execução. É criado chamando Sequelize.transaction(). Para executar uma consulta em uma transação, você deve passar a transação no objeto de opções."
Fonte: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/transaction.js~Transaction.html